# Issue with custom dialog after removing Kotlin extension from the Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding, kotlin-extension

I have a custom dialog in my android project and it was working fine. After I removed `kotlin extension` from the project, I have modified my code as follows but there is some issue with the Views in the custom dialog. Codes `etTitle.visibility = View.GONE` and `val newRequest = etDetail.text.toString()` didn't work as I expected. It didn't hide the view `etTitle` and the value in the `EditText` `etDetail` is not picked also, it always returns emplty even when there is some value.

```
private lateinit var bindingDialogLayout: CustomDialogBinding

fun specialRequestDialog(currentRequest: String?) {

        bindingDialogLayout = CustomDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        val dialogLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null)
        val etTitle = bindingDialogLayout.etTitle
        val etDetail = bindingDialogLayout.etDetails

        etTitle.visibility = View.GONE

        etDetail.setText(currentRequest)

        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setTitle("What is your special request?")
            .setCancelable(false)

            .setPositiveButton("Save") { dialog, which ->

                val newRequest = etDetail.text.toString()

                if (newRequest.isEmpty()) {
                    showErrorSnackBar("Type in if you have any special request, else hit cancel", true)
                } else {

                    addButton.visibility = View.GONE
                    deleteButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                }
            }

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->

                dialog?.dismiss()

            }
            .setView(dialogLayout)
            .show()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the wrong view to the dialog.
Use this instead:

`.setView(bindingDialogLayout.root)`